# Pass parameter to Junit TestCase from JUnitCore

Tags: java, junit

I am using JUnitCore.run to execute a TestCase Class. I want to pass parameter to my test methods. Or May be initalize the TestCase class with a parameterised constructor. Any way of doing this?

regards
Souvik

Answer (score 0):

You can use [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). They can be passed on the command line by passing `-Dkey=value` to `java` and accessed in your test via the `java.util.Properties` class

That being said usually unit tests should not require passing in values from the command line. Perhaps the Parameterized runner would meet your needs.